# Unite two queries, 1 returns list of ids the other shows other data

Tags: mysql, sql

I've first query that returns list of ids based on search term:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.user_id) AS user_id_array
  FROM words_en AS w
  JOIN connections AS c
    ON w.id = c.word_id
 WHERE w.word = "love"
```

Thank I've query that returns profile of user:

```
SELECT id, email, verified, level, name_surname, age, sex, profession, education, location, privacy, suspend FROM users LIMIT :start, :results
```

Second query needs to do IN() on the returned list of first query. How do I do that?

I need:

```
SELECT id, email, verified, level, name_surname, age, sex, profession, education, location, privacy, suspend FROM users LIMIT :start, :results IN(user_id_array)
```

I could have used php in between, but that's not fun :)

I came up with this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.verified, u.level, u.name_surname, u.age, u.sex, u.profession, u.education, u.location, u.privacy, u.suspend
  FROM words_en AS w
  JOIN connections AS c
    ON w.id = c.word_id
  JOIN users AS u
    ON u.id = c.user_id
 WHERE w.word = "love"
```

But isn't it inefficient? I first combine 3 tables and than I do select... seems not right.

Comment: The only real way to tell if the combined query is better than the individual queries is to do some profile.  Usually, `JOIN` statements are much better because you aren't filtering tables twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter (w.word = "love") gives 1 row from 'words_en'
Select from 'connections' with filter on word_id gives many unique users (because connections is many-to-many link with unique pair of user_id + word_id)
Join with 'users' saves row count because 'users' have primary key as user_id.

So you have exactly user count which related to 'love' keyword.
Fully equivalent query.